# file_get_contents returns false on localhost

Tags: php, localhost, file-get-contents

I'm trying to get the contents of my local server webpage like this :

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
$page_content = file_get_contents('http://myhost.local/some_page');
var_dump($page_content);
```

it always returns false. But when I change http://myhost.local to http://google.com I get google page, so it's not allow_url_fopen. Curl works the same way.
Any ideas?

Comment: Does the page show up in a browser on the same system as the PHP with the same URL? And what does the log say or any errors?

Comment: Does `file_get_contents('http://localhost/some_page')` work?

Comment: Yes, of course, I can open it in browser. There is no error.

Comment: I don't have localhost pointing to that local server

Comment: Can you post the content of your hosts file? (probably /private/etc/hosts if you're on OSX). Also, curious if Curl works, from the command-line or otherwise.

Comment: thanks @MalcolmDiggs you pointed me to right direction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. I'm developing on windows having debian virtual machine, so I added myhost.local to windows hosts file, but not to linux host file, therefore php running on linux could not resolve it's own host.